# How would I have an Android KitKat app do something when the device itself goes into suspend mode?

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

Is there some sort of intent, some sort of overrideable method in `Context`, etc. that will allow an app to respond to a [system suspend](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/suspend-mode) event?

Comment: if the device goes into suspend mode, wouldn't any event (including the intent) also get `suspended` until the system wakes? or do u want an intent to respond to waking from a suspend state?

Comment: I'm looking for an intent that would be fired prior to the device going into suspend mode.